# Who is affected by an area buff?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Righteous Wrath of the Faithful (SpC) is an area buff that has a round per level duration, a 30 ft range and target: all allies 30 ft from you.

Is it a buff on each target that was 30 ft from me when I cast the spell?
Is it an area buff that moves with me and affect all allies 30 ft from me?
Is it a buff on each target that lasts for the duration and as long as they never get outside the range?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It applies a buff that lasts 1 round per level on each ally who is in 30 ft. of you at the time you cast it. The allies cannot lose the buff by moving away, but new allies also cannot benefit by moving closer. After the casting, it is a buff operating independently on each ally who was in range.

For effects that cover an area for a duration, the game uses the **Area** property, typically with an **emanation** (e.g. [*consecrate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/consecrate.htm)) or **spread** (e.g. [*entangle*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/entangle.htm)), or the **Effect** property, describing an effect that takes up physical space (e.g. [*resilient sphere*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/resilientSphere.htm)). If the emanation is to move with a creature, it uses the phrase “centered on” (e.g. [*magic circle against evil*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicCircleAgainstEvil.htm)).